# Need to generate proper greeting when inputting 24 hr time in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, input, time, conditional-statements

I am writing a program that generates an appropriate output when inputting a 24 hr time. Example: 930 is 9.30 am; 2345 is 11.45 pm. Midnight is zero. Program responds with a suitable greeting for the time of day (e.g., “Good morning”, “Good afternoon”, or “Good evening”).

I have the below so far which works fine:

```py
time = int(input())

if time < 0 or time > 2359:
    print("Invalid time entered. Please try again.")
else:
    if time >= 0 and time <= 1159:
        print("Good morning!")
    elif time >= 1200 and time <= 1759:
        print("Good Afternoon!")
    elif time >= 1800 and time <= 2359:
        print("Good Evening!")`
```

To make it harder, I want to make the program respond with a “?” if the time represented by the number is impossible, such as 2400, -5 or 1163.

However I am unsure how to account for these conditions.

Is there a better or cleaner way of creating a condition to account for this?

Comment: You can display the time as such by using `f'{str(time[:-2])}.{str(time[-2:])}'`. The invalid time can be achieved by checking if `time % 100 < 60`, which checks if the time ends with at most 59 minutes.

Comment: The `?` part is a bit confusing; do you want to replace the current `Invalid time entered` message?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct. You're already accounting for `-5` and `2400`, and the existing conditions seem correct.

To catch `1163` you can use the [`%` (modulo)](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) operator to get the last two digits with `time % 100` and reject values above 59. Additionally, you can simplify most of your conditions because the lower ranges were already checked in previous branches.

```py
time = int(input())

if time < 0 or time >= 2400 or time % 100 >= 60:
    print('?')
elif time <= 1159:
    print("Good morning!")
elif time <= 1759:
    print("Good Afternoon!")
elif time <= 2359:
    print("Good Evening!")
```

Answer (score 0):

the only loophole in your code is that you can say : 1160 ( 3 digit is a 6 ,7,8,9) the way to fix it is to add another condition to the first if statment :  ( we call out the 3 digit of the string and see if its 6,7,8,9)

```
time = int(input())
if time < 0 or time > 2359  or str(time)[2] in ["6","7","8","9"]:
    print("Invalid time entered. Please try again.")
else:
    if time >= 0 and time <= 1159:
        print("Good morning!")
    elif time >= 1160 and time <= 1759:
        print("Good Afternoon!")
    elif time >= 1760 and time <= 2400:
        print("Good Evening!")
```

Comment: Would be simpler to just use `time % 100 > 60`.

Comment: ( im new to python still) where do i put this time % 100 > 60 ?

Comment: There's a problem in your indentation (all your `elif`s should be indented), and the string method is clever but doesn't catch times like `2261`.

Comment: fixed it BoppreH - pasted it wrong my bad ;D